# Is there anyway to fix ssl handshake error on android 4.x ,Failure in SSL library protocol error

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am developing and android native woocomerce app i am facing issue that when i use to build and generate apk and run on android version 4.x it donot fetch data from api just shows an SSL error caused by protocol :
**ATTACHED BELOW IN PICTURE** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pvLh.png)
Versions above 4.x i.e 5 or soo on work fine and fetch all the data

i had tried TLS conversion but not get succesfull

```
package com.app.androidwoocommerce.network;


import com.app.androidwoocommerce.constant.ConstantValues;
import com.app.androidwoocommerce.oauth.BasicOAuth;
import com.app.androidwoocommerce.oauth.OAuthInterceptor;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;


/**
 * APIClient handles all the Network API Requests using Retrofit Library
 **/

public class APIClient {

    public static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static APIRequests apiRequests;
    private static final String BASE_URL = ConstantValues.WOOCOMMERCE_URL;


    // Singleton Instance of APIRequests
    public static APIRequests getInstance() {
        if (apiRequests == null) {

            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

            OAuthInterceptor oauth1Woocommerce = new OAuthInterceptor.Builder()
                    .consumerKey(ConstantValues.WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_KEY)
                    .consumerSecret(ConstantValues.WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_SECRET)
                    .build();

            BasicOAuth basicOAuthWoocommerce = new BasicOAuth.Builder()
                    .consumerKey(ConstantValues.WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_KEY)
                    .consumerSecret(ConstantValues.WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_SECRET)
                    .build();

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .addInterceptor(BASE_URL.startsWith("http://")?  oauth1Woocommerce : basicOAuthWoocommerce)
                    .build();
           /* OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .addInterceptor(BASE_URL.startsWith("http://")?  oauth1Woocommerce : basicOAuthWoocommerce)
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .build();*/


            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();


            apiRequests = retrofit.create(APIRequests.class);

            return apiRequests;

        }
        else {
            return apiRequests;
        }
    }

}
```

**I expect that API connect with devices 4.x also the same way in other android versions min SDK is already been checked its somekind of ssl or tls issues i think**

Answer (score 0):

Code is not written by me, but I got it in my project and I can confirm it works.

```
fun Context.installTls12() {
    // important code starts here
    try {
        ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this)
    } catch (e: GooglePlayServicesRepairableException) {
        // Prompt the user to install/update/enable Google Play services.
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().showErrorNotification(this, e.connectionStatusCode)
    } catch (e: GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException) {
        // Indicates a non-recoverable error: let the user know.
    }
}
```

The Java version should look very similarly. Call this early on. The Kotlin extension isn't required but very useful to have.

Comment: not sure about that i am new to android and java not getting where to place it or what  is the functionality can u please integrete that in my exsisting code ?

Comment: its very nice to talk to you soo that after integration i can test and give feedback ..
reguards

Comment: Place the try-catch code in your MainActivity onCreate